# How come the class variable is not updating when the function is adding 1?

Tags: python

```
class Score:
    def __init__(self):
        self._Colour = (0, 0, 139)
        self.__x = 30
        self.__y = 0
        self._Shape = pygame.Rect((self.__x, self.__y), (200, 50))
        self.Team1Score = 0.  # THIS VARIABLE WILL NOT UPDATE IF 1 IS ADDED TO IT
        self.Team2Score = 0.  # THIS VARIABLE WILL NOT UPDATE IF 1 IS ADDED TO IT
        self._Title = f"{self.Team1Score}  -  {self.Team2Score}"
        self._text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 30).render(self._Title, True, (255, 255, 255))
        self._text_rect = self._text_type.get_rect(center=self._Shape.center)
        self.Score = False
        self.teamRect1 = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (50, 50))
        self.teamRect2 = pygame.Rect((210, 0), (50, 50))
        self.TeamNames = []
        self.Teams = []

    def TeamSort(self, team):
        team_total = 0
        for key, value in team.items():
            if team_total == 2:
                break
            else:
                if value.Team not in self.TeamNames:
                    self.TeamNames.append(value.Team)
                    team_total += 1

        for team in self.TeamNames:
            if len(self.Teams) == 2:
                break
            else:
                newName = (team[0:3].upper())
                self.TeamNames.remove(team)
                self.Teams.append(newName)

    def DrawScore(self, window, team):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self._Colour, self._Shape)
        window.blit(self._text_type, self._text_rect)
        self.DrawNames(window, team)

    def DrawNames(self, window, team):
        self.TeamSort(team)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), self.teamRect1)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), self.teamRect2)
        if len(self.Teams) == 2:
            teamOne = self.Teams[0]
            teamTwo = self.Teams[1]
            text_type1 = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 20).render(teamOne, True, (0, 0, 0))
            text_type2 = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 20).render(teamTwo, True, (0, 0, 0))
            window.blit(text_type1, (self.teamRect1.x, self.teamRect1.y + 10))
            window.blit(text_type2, (self.teamRect2.x, self.teamRect2.y + 10))

    def AddScore(self, p1, p2, window):
        print(self.Team1Score, self.Team2Score)
        if p1.Shooting:
            if p1.Colour == (255, 0, 0):
                self.Team1Score += 1.  # THIS DOES NOT UPDATE THE VARIABLE IT STAYS AS 0
        elif p2.Shooting:
            if not p1.Shooting and p1.Colour == (255, 255, 255):
                self.Team1Score += 1.  # THIS DOES NOT UPDATE THE VARIABLE IT STAYS AS 0

        if p1.Shooting:
            if p1.Colour == (255, 255, 255):
                self.Team2Score += 1
        elif p2.Shooting:
            if not p1.Shooting and p1.Colour == (255, 0, 0):
                self.Team2Score += 1

        pygame.draw.rect(window, self._Colour, self._Shape)
        self._Title = f"{self.Team1Score}  -  {self.Team2Score}"
        self._text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 40).render(f"{self._Title}", True, (0, 0, 0))
        window.blit(self._text_type, self._text_rect)

    def WinCalc(self):
        print(self.Team1Score, self.Team2Score)
        if self.Team1Score > self.Team2Score:
            return 'Team1'
        elif self.Team2Score > self.Team1Score:
            return 'Team2'
        else:
            return 'Draw'
```

The function AddScore() does not update the variables self.Team1Score or self.Team2Score. I do not understand why it is not changing as when it is blitted on the screen it changes, only the variable seems to not change. Do I need an update function for the variable?

Comment: Why do you think that the `self.Team1Score` and `self.Team2Score` attributes are not changed?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I do not know that's why I am asking you

Comment: I ask you how you recognize that it does not change. Is `self.Team1Score += 1. ` ever executed? Is the condition `if p1.Colour == (255, 0, 0):` ever  `True`? Why are you testing the color of the players? That seems strange.

Comment: @Rabbid76 this function is ran in another file, but when it does run and the boolean is executed the variables do not change with the +1. Just imagine that in this file the function has ran without the boolean.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is not reproducible with the information given in the question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please add print statements around your addition code. If they do print, then the variable will be updated. If not, then the variable or the addition is **not** the problem